# Mixing Akka agents with legacy code that changes the same data

Tags: java, akka

We have recently started using Akka in our software, but most of our code is still "traditional" Java code. I am now in a position where I want to use Akka with existing classes, but can't rewrite all the existing code that also uses these classes.

In particular, I have a class that manages a map of data objects. The map is already used concurrently by different threads, so the manager class makes sure that all access to the map is synchronized. I now have to create a cleanup job that removes objects from the map after they have become irrelevant. Since this job is supposed to run asynchronously in the background, I use an Akka agent, i.e. I have code that looks more or less like this:

```
Agent< ObjectManager > myObjectManagerAgent = new Agent< ObjectManager >( myObjectManager, myActorSystem );

...

myObjectManagerAgent.sendOff(
    new Function< ObjectManager, ObjectManager >()
    {
        @Override
        public ObjectManager apply( final ObjectManager objectManager )
        {
           ...

           objectManager.erase( irrelevantObjectIds );

           return objectManager;
        }
     }
  );
```

However, the same object manager is also written to directly, without the agent, from several other places within the software. As mentioned, this access is thread-safe, but knows nothing of Akka, actors, or agents.

Now my question is: Is this... well, I'm sure it's not advisable, but will this work? Or am I shooting myself in the foot here? Even if it will work in general, are there potential traps or safety measures I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite normal to use Akka to call into existing code, which is all you're doing here.  You state that the ObjectManager is thread-safe and that other parts of the software use it as well, so there's no reason to think that introducing Akka will inherently cause problems.  On the other hand, you could also move your core logic into an Akka actor, then provide a simple facade over it for your non-Akka consumers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit confusing to see this object being wrapped inside an Agent (which you typically do to make it safe to share an unsynchronized mutable resource across multiple threads or executions contexts, while in fact it is not only thread-safe on its own but also mutated without going through the agent. It might be okay while migrating the whole program to the agent-based approach, but it strikes me as odd if it is meant to stay like that. I’d rather not involve agents at all in that case.

Comment: For the record, I agree with this as well.  He said he knew it may be ill-advised and asked simply if it would work.  It will work, but to your point it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: The plan is definitely to have the class completely managed by an agent, and to get rid of the internal synchronization. But it will take me a while to get there, so I was looking for some kind of partial solution until then. Thank you both for your answers!